# SQL - one table - count of multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple schools with multiple grade levels and a variety of statuses.
I need to get the count of each grade in each school if status is -1 or 0
This is all from the same table.  'Students'
I need a count if grade is equal to 0 and school equal to 1234 
next to that count if grade equal to 1 and school equal to 1234
next to that count if grade equal to 2 and school equal to 1234
The next line would be for a different school, etc.  Each line a different school each column a grade level from 0 to 12.

I tried

```
select Sched_NextYearGrade,
    sum(case when Sched_NextYearGrade = ‘1’ then 1 else 0 end) as 'firstcount'
    sum(case when Sched_NextYearGrade = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as 'secondCount'
from Students 
Where (ENROLL_STATUS BETWEEN -1 AND 0)
group by Sched_NextYearGrade
```

I get

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance

Comment: You have Microsoft curly quotes around the "1" in your first `sum`.  And your column aliases are incorrect.  If you really, really want a case-sensitive alias, you'd use double quotes `as "firstCount"`.  But generally you want to avoid that like the plague.  You're generally much better off using normal case-insentitive identifiers with no double quotes `as firstCount`.

Answer (score 3):

`‘1’` has the wrong quotes. They should be simple quotes: `'1'`.